# Displaying stats and calculating the average from certain user inputs

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, average, user-input, calculator

I have this application that I needed to create for my class project and I am down to my last part (minus the int validation for the scanner).

This app needs to be able to accept any amount of user input from the scanner, but the user can only enter numbers that are between 0-100 (for example, 10 100's, 20 0's, etc). To stop it, the user will type in "999" and when they type in "999", that is when the application will stop asking for numbers.

At that point, I have to display certain stats for the valid numbers (aka the numbers that are between 0-100). The stats that I need to show is this: The total numbers that was entered, the highest number, the lowest number, and the average of all of those numbers.

Can't figure out how I would do that.

Here is the code:
https://gist.github.com/tcipack/8f1ed6bd0d7d79b158ee191d228b0a24

Comment: Do you have any code so far, you said you are down to the last part, show your code so far.

Comment: You'll likely want to store the values you read from the input in a List (e.g. ArrayList). Then you can perform operations on the list to get the size of the list (total numbers entered), you can sort it to get the highest and lowest, and you can average by looping over the list

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add the code. Here it is

Comment: https://gist.github.com/tcipack/8f1ed6bd0d7d79b158ee191d228b0a24

Comment: OK, so when user enters negative number, like -20, what is code supposed to do ? Ask him to enter it again or store it in the array/collection along with all the valid numbers and ignore it when displaying stats ?

Comment: Any negative numbers or any numbers above 100 should be ignored. It's like an actual score grade from a test. If it happens, it should ask them to re-enter a valid number (between 0-100). Only the valid numbers should be in the array, or at least, those in-valid numbers should be ignored when displaying the stats

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that can possibly help you get started, based on your current code.

Create a new `List` at the beginning, and then add the scores to it if it is within the range of 0-100. Then, when "999" is entered, use that list to calculate the results.

The lines that are commented out are the lines I added:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input =  new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a score or \"999\" to end the program.");
    int score;
//  List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    do {
        score = input.nextInt();

        if(score != 999) {
            if(score<0 || score >100) {
                System.out.println("Only use scores that are between 0-100.");
//          } else {
//              numbers.add(score);
            }
            System.out.println("Enter another score or \"999\" to end the program.");
        } else {
//          HERE: Use the numbers list to calculate the results
            System.out.println("END THE PROGRAM. Results:");
        }
    } while (score != 999);
}
```

An example of how you can calculate the results:

```
int max     = numbers.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).max().getAsInt();
int min     = numbers.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).min().getAsInt();
int average = numbers.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).average().getAsDouble();
int size    = numbers.size();
```

Comment: Do I have to insert something else?

Comment: @AshT yes you need to calculate the results and then print them. I have added an example of how to calculate the results using streams.

Answer (score 0):

OK so here's one of the possibilities:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[]args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> listOfNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

        int number;

        System.out.print("Enter your number: ");

        while ((number = in.nextInt()) != 999){

            while (number < 0 || number > 100){
                System.out.print("Invalid input. Try again: ");
                number = in.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.print("Enter your number: ");
            listOfNumbers.add(number);
        }


        int maxNumber = listOfNumbers.stream().mapToInt(x -> x).max().getAsInt();
        int minNumber = listOfNumbers.stream().mapToInt(x -> x).min().getAsInt();
        double average = listOfNumbers.stream().mapToInt(x -> x).average().getAsDouble();
        int totalEntered = listOfNumbers.size();

        System.out.printf("Out of %d numbers entered, max is %d, min is %d and average is %.2f", totalEntered,
                                                                      maxNumber,minNumber,average);


    }
}
```

Sample test:

Enter your number: 5

Enter your number: 10

Enter your number: -12

Invalid input. Try again: 9

Enter your number: 999

Out of 3 numbers entered, max is 10, min is 5 and average is 8.00

I used [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) methods to quickly get min, max and average, then we just print it out.